# Why the port number is cut when angular app call rest service

Tags: rest, angularjs

I have rest service:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/brands
```

When I test it from web browser it works well.

I use it in angular service:

```
var motoAdsServices = angular.module('motoAdsServices', ['ngResource']);

motoAdsServices.factory('Brand', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/:id', {}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          id: 'brands'
        },
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  }]);
```

When it is call I have error because in reqest URL I don't have port number:

```
Request URL: http://localhost/api/brands
```

Why the port numer is is cut? Angular cut it?

In [Angular doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) is written:

*A parametrized URL template with parameters prefixed by : as in /user/:username. If you are using a URL with a port number (e.g. `http://example.com:8080/api`), it will be respected.*

**UPDATE**

I use angular version 1.0.8 (thank @KayakDave for your attention) but [Angular doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) applies to version 1.2.

Comment: Thanks. My misspelling I updated it. I have 3 services `brands`, `countries`, `adverts`. None of them work. So the question still current.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?  non-escaped port number support was added in 1.2 (here's the PR: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2778)

Comment: Angular 1.0.8. So this version do not respect port. But `\\` not working for me.

Comment: I escaped port number using double backslash and it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has a colon and therefore gets stripped, kind of like :id. If you escape it, you should be ok. Try `http://localhost\:3000/api/:id` instead. You may run into this again in routes or other places.
There is [an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1243) regarding this behavior in case something changes.

**Updated:** `http://localhost\\:3000/api/:id`

Comment: `http://localhost\:3000/api/:id` It doesn't work for me. Are you sure? Angular doc say something different. Read it at the end of my question.

Comment: I escaped port number using double backslash and it works. It is solution from `an issue` link. Now I have: Origin `http://localhost:8000` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. But problem from my question is solved :)

Comment: [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1664] suggested escaping $resource in  1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.1.0 and 1.1.1.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time. Already spent 4 hours to search why this issue :-/

Answer (score 2):

Because angular intercept the url and consider the `:any` as a parameter that you should pass to it.

An easy way to hack this is to put `\:3000` in your url.

```
motoAdsServices.factory('Brand', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000\:3000/api/:id', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                id: 'brands'
            },
            isArray: true
        }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for the resource plugin issue:

```
 var fixedTargetUrl = TARGET_URL.replace(/(:\d{4})/, "\\$1");
```